# json_encode($response ); how handle Json API, extract json format with Laravel

Tags: php, json, laravel-5, guzzle

I'm stuck with JSON.

I can receive data via API GET response, by using Guzzle.

I'm trying to extract data to key:value format with Laravel 5.7,
   to able save it mysql db, which is version 5.55 (does not understand JSON format)

and handle it with Blade able to show it enduser.

```
 use GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Response;
```

/// Getting Response ///

```
  $data = json_decode( (string) $response->getBody() );
  echo $response->getBody() ;
```

JSON Response format is:

```
{
  "type": "fi.prh.opendata.bis",
  "version": "1",
  "totalResults": -1,
  "resultsFrom": 0,
  "previousResultsUri": null,
  "nextResultsUri": null,
  "exceptionNoticeUri": null,
  "results": [ // <- IN this part has company information
    {
      "businessId": "0856064-3",
      "name": "Company Ltd",
      "registrationDate": "1991-09-18",
      "companyForm": "Ltd",
      "detailsUri": null,
      "liquidations": [

      ],
      "names": [ // <- other array, which has history of Company names
        {
          "order": 0,
          "version": 1,
          "name": "Company Ltd",
          "registrationDate": "1991-08-14",
          "endDate": null,
          "source": 1
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

1) Tried to extract company information "results": from array.

```
echo $response->getBody()->getContents([results]);
```

Just getting ERROR: Class App\PRHData does not exist which is same 
 file as having code.

2) Tried to extract company information "results": from array.

```
 foreach($data[result[0]]['businessId'] as $i => $v)
 {
 echo $v['businessId'].'<br/>';
 }
```

I'm getting error:

```
 Use of undefined constant result - assumed 'result' (this will 
 throw an Error in a future version of PHP)
```

I do not have any idea what is that error message.

---

```
use GuzzleHttp\Client;
use GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Request as GuzzleRequest;
use GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Response;
use GuzzleHttp\Psr7;

class PRHData extends Model
{
public static function getJson()
{
```

/// Sending request /// This part works, I'm getting data via API.

```
$client = new Client([
   'base_uri' => 'https://avoindata.prh.fi/bis/v1/',
   'defaults'=>[
     'timeout'  => 2.0,
     'cookies' => true,
     'headers'  => ['content-type' => 'application/json']]
  ]);
  $response = $client->request('GET','0856064-3'); //<- number is 
                             parameter for GET request to API call
```

/// End of Sending request ///

/// Getting Response ///

```
 $data = json_decode( (string) $response->getBody() ); // WORKS! 
 echo $response->getBody() ;   // Works !!!!
```

1) I'm looking for way to get information under "result" array
to key:value format like:

```
$VatId = $value['businessId'];
$Name = $value{'name'];
$RegDate = $value['registrationDate'];
$companyForm = $value['companyForm'];
```

and so on, to able save them db.

Output from response so far:

```
"results": // <- IN this part has company information

[{"businessId":"0856064-3",

"name":"Company Ltd",

"registrationDate":"1991-09-18",

"companyForm":"Ltd",
```

Thanks MikroMike

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can access it using the result of your `json_decode`, which parses the JSON into PHP objects/arrays:

```php
//...
$data = json_decode( (string) $response->getBody() );

$VatId = $data->results[0]->businessId;
```

Note that this will only ever access the first company at index 0. You can use a `foreach` loop to traverse every result:

```php
//...
$data = json_decode( (string) $response->getBody() );

foreach ($data->results as $company) {
    $VatId = $company->businessId;
    // Do something with it in the iteration
}
```

Comment: That's the way, it works great, thanks.

Which raise me one more question:

-  When there will be more than one company information
   I need to use Fofeach loop like this

     foreach($data->results[0]->businessId as $i => $v)
     {
     echo $v['businessId'].'<br/>';
     }
 
Gives me error: "Invalid argument supplied for foreach()"

Comment: @MikroMike you need to `foreach` the `results` array. I updated the answer with an example.

Comment: You as author of the question have to check my answer as "accepted" @mikromike